# Error "layout was not declared" when compiling Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qmake

I have a problem with this layout. I wrote this example in a .cpp file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QSpinBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget *window = new QWidget;
  window -> setWindowTitle("Enter your age please:");
  QSpinBox *spinBox = new QSpinBox;

  layout -> addWidget(spinBox);
  window -> show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

I compiled with these commands:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

I get this error:

```
age.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
age.cpp:13:3: error: ‘layout’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [age.o] Error 1
```

I've searched for this error but could not find any solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: You haven't declared a varibale `layout` as you declared `window` or `app`. Now you get it? :)

Comment: Please read your compiler errors.

Comment: Yeesh, poor OP getting all those -1's. We all make mistakes and were new once.

Answer (score 4):

It is clearly not declared in your source code. You should first declare a QGridLayout variable, for example, as follows:

```
QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared layout. you need somthing like this

```
  // add this
  QLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  window->setLayout(layout);
```